Emulating `<textarea>` background color on a `<div>` in dark mode
I'd like to get the background color of a textarea when dark mode is applied so I can apply it to a <div> which I want to 'emulate' a <textarea>. This seems pretty straightforward, since it doesn't need to be pure CSS.
I just get the color when the light and dark color-scheme are applied. Here's an example for getting the dark-mode background color:


let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.style.colorScheme = "dark";
document.body.append(textarea);
console.log(getComputedStyle(textarea)["background-color"]);



The problem is, this doesn't work in Chrome. It returns rgb(18, 18, 18) which is much darker than the actual background color which is rgb(59, 59, 59). It seems to be doing something weird with transparency even though the actual background color is opaque. Or maybe it has some sort of "virtual" background which is not accessible to getComputedStyle.

I'm not sure what rgb(18, 18, 18) corresponds to here.
It's also possible that this is a bug, but it seems more likely that it's just a user-agent specific thing that I need to take into account. If it's the latter case, how could the above code be corrected?

I know this is not a proper answer, but may lead to a satisfactory conclusion.
Here's the reproduction of the problem (at least in Chrome):


console.clear();

const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
const div = document.createElement('div');

textarea.style.colorScheme = 'dark';
textarea.textContent = 'TEXTAREA.CONTENT';
div.textContent = 'DIV.CONTENT';

document.body.appendChild(textarea);
document.body.appendChild(div);

const style = getComputedStyle(textarea);

for ( const rule of style )
{
  const ruleValue = style[rule];
  
  div.style[rule] = ruleValue;
}



Then, here's my findings...
If I apply the same rules that I got from textarea to div and itself, they'll both look the same (at least in Chrome).


console.clear();

const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
const div = document.createElement('div');

textarea.style.colorScheme = 'dark';
textarea.textContent = 'TEXTAREA.CONTENT';
div.textContent = 'DIV.CONTENT';

document.body.appendChild(textarea);
document.body.appendChild(div);

const style = getComputedStyle(textarea);

for ( const rule of style )
{
  const ruleValue = style[rule];
  
  div.style[rule] = ruleValue;
  textarea.style[rule] = ruleValue;
}



So, what I can infer from this behavior is that the user-agent is computing the style wrong (I mean the result of getComputedStyle()). Because I didn't change the nature of any element, only their styles... And giving the same style back to <textarea> will make it looks like the <div>.
My conclusion is that this is a bug in Chrome getComputedStyle() implementation.
Also, I found out that the same happens in Microsoft Edge, but not in Safari. I didn't test in Firefox.
